# Realizing real time Collaborative GUI with Java?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, swing, user-interface, implementation

I wanted to create a real time collaborative GUI ,  as far as my knowledge is concern, i thought java swing MVC roots can play some role in that and can provide the basis. Am i right? i wanted to have experts reviews.

Which network technology/library will be suitable for this purpose and could give the high level support?

**example usecase:** If one client press the button or move the slider every client's button or slider move etc same for other swing elements?

Please share your ideas if you think something is achievable and can work as an small example or proof-of-concept.

Jibbylala

Answer (score 2):

You likely won't find any out of the box solution to do exactly what you want, but you should be able to leverage existing technologies to do this. If you have a central server, you could use that to coordinate the clients. When one client does something, it could send a message to the server, which would then broadcast out to the other clients (the client could register with the server receive these notifications). If you don't have/want a central server, you could use UDP broadcasting, and clients could broadcast out their activities, and the other clients could listen and synchronize themselves.

Another challenge will be coming up with a messaging protocol to indicate what has changed. Do you envision needing *every* UI action to be broadcast (i.e. every button press, every component movement, etc), or will it just be a subset of them. If it is all of them, you might want to come up with a generic solution, like set property X on component Y, etc.

Hope this helps.